# Why do macOS application-specific keyboard shortcuts involving modifiers: ⌥, ⇧ not work with latest Chrome?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome

macOS configured per-application keyboard shortcuts including at least ⌥+⇧ (Option+Shift) are broken.

Occurs with Google Chrome version:
`69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

And macOS Mojave, version:
`10.14 (18A391)`

And the previous version of macOS, `10.13`.

Problem:
When you configure an application-specific macOS keyboard shortcut for Google Chrome that includes holding the keys ⌥ and ⇧, and pressing any other key, it doesn't work. It may also work for keyboard shortcuts for other modifiers, but I haven't checked.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the "Keyboard" preferences pane in System Preferences, then click on the "Shortcuts" tab
2. Select "App Shortcuts" from the left window pane
3. Click the "+" button to add a new app shortcut
4. Select "Google Chrome" as the Application, and "Select Next Tab" as the Menu Title, and press ⌥+⇧+K as the keyboard shortcut
5. Click "Add" to save the application-specific shortcut
6. Open Chrome and notice that not only does it not work, it actually prints a "" symbol if you have focus on any text field

This probably happens because Chrome is likely ignoring keyboard shortcuts and interpreting keypresses as Unicode shortcuts.

Is this a bug in Google Chrome?

Do you also see this behaviour?

Comment: I can confirm your findings

Comment: Probably Googles new dumbass feature. Add it to the list right after getting rid of urls.